# Remove RANK() column from output

Tags: sql, rank

I use the RANK() function in the following script to obtain observations on the most recent date for each portfolio. However, while I am very satisfied with output that the script provides, I was wondering if it is possible to leave out the column 'rank' in the output.

```
SELECT
 tbl.*
FROM
(SELECT 
 a.from_date fromdate, 
 a.portfolio,
 a.var1,
 a.var2,
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.portfolio ORDER BY a.from_date DESC) AS rank 
FROM 
 table1 a, 
INNER JOIN
 table2 b
ON
 a.portfolio_ref=b.por_ref
) tbl
WHERE
 tbl.rank = 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just specify the columns you want instead of `tbl.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you can select the columns you want in the outer query:

```
select fromdate, portolio, var1, var2
from . . .
```

You could also use a correlated subquery:

One method would be to use a correlated subquery instead:

```
SELECT a.from_date as fromdate, a.portfolio,
       a.var1, a.var2
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.portfolio_ref = b.por_ref
WHERE a.from_date = (SELECT MAX(a2.from_date)
                     FROM table1 a2
                     WHERE a2.portfolio = a.portfolio
                    );
```